# ASP.NET MembershipProvider membership info (usernames, passwords) not being stored? How would I implement this system in a networked environment?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am working on a project in ASP.NET using MembershipProvider for my login system. Our issue is that the ASPNETDB file generated by ASP.NET upon creation of the login system seems to be empty or is not properly storing member information. Our project is a Web Site project, and we ran into a weird case of not being able to maintain login info. I gave my colleague my ASPNETDB file, he overwrote his and yet the login system was still using his old member information, it would not recognize the new ASPNETDB file. So I'm assuming the issue is that the member information is not being stored in that specific file as I was expecting.

How do we remedy this? We need to install this system for a client, so we will probably host the site sometime soon, how do we localize the membership information so that it's consistent across multiple workstations? Right now the membership info seems to be tied to specific computers. And when we go into the ASPNETDB file there doesn't seem to be anything there.

Can anyone shine some light on this? Its been happening for a while now.

Comment: How do you generate ASPNETDB? Could you upload web.config *masked out credentials*?

Comment: My colleague just found ANOTHER ASPNETDB file, this one was stored on the SQL server localDB. Turns out that's the one containing all the information, and the one stored locally in our project isn't even doing anything. So now we know where it's storing the data, we just need to find out how we could switch it so that it uses the ASPNETDB file in the project folder rather than the SQL server. This explains why memberships were different for each workstation, but I still don't know how to make it so that it always pulls from the same location (project directory) instead of SQL server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I still don't know how to make it so that it always pulls from the
>   same location (project directory) instead of SQL server.

In ASP.NET Membership, connection strings for **memership** and **roleManager** are in web.config. You just need to update them accordingly.

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="SqlConnection"/>
    <add name="SqlConnection" connectionString="..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="SqlConnection" ... />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add connectionStringName="SqlConnection" ../>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
</configuration>
```